# JS How to use relative units in a condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, viewport-units

I have a div, that is 15vh high. In javascript I sometimes change it's height to 20vh. My question is, **How to make a condition, if *"the div's height"* == 15vh, do something?** When I use jquery `.css("height")`the returned value is in pixels and  `.height()` does the same. Because I'm learning, I'd appreciate as simple solution as possible, or a breaf explanation of what's happening.

Comment: Since you’re learning, I’ll recommend you design a little differently. Rather than making some conditional off an element height, use some variable in your code to decide what you set the divs height to and use the same variable for your other conditional. This makes for easier to understand, maintain, and modify code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(window).height()` will give you the value of `1vh` in `px`.

So you can make a condition if `"the div's height" == 15 * $(window).height()`